# Public / Private in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I generated some scaffold for a title (string) and the body (content) called 'documents' to allow users to post things.

The problem is is that anybody can view the document. Is there a way to make it "private" so only the user can view it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to setup authentication in your app. Then you'll only allow logged in users to view the document and reject the others.

Watch this excellent railscast: [Authentication from Scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch).